# Saxon .Net read xml from stream

Tags: vb.net, xml-parsing, saxon

all examples show how to read an xml from an local file. But how do I read a xml from a url or a stream and process it further?

Example: http://www.oreillynet.com/xml/blog/2006/03/hello_saxon_on_net_an_aspnet_i.html

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for XsltExamples.cs in the saxon-resources download available on both Sourceforge and www.saxonica.com. The very first example seems to do what you are asking for.

```
public static void ExampleSimple1(String sourceUri, String xsltUri) {

        // Create a Processor instance.
        Processor processor = new Processor();

        // Load the source document
        XdmNode input = processor.NewDocumentBuilder().Build(new Uri(sourceUri));

        // Create a transformer for the stylesheet.
        XsltTransformer transformer = processor.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(new Uri(xsltUri)).Load();

        // Set the root node of the source document to be the initial context node
        transformer.InitialContextNode = input;

        // Create a serializer
        Serializer serializer = new Serializer();
        serializer.SetOutputWriter(Console.Out);

        // Transform the source XML to System.out.
        transformer.Run(serializer);
    }
```

Comment: Perfect! I will buy you a beer, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an XmlDocument object for reading the XML? If so, you'll want [XMLDocument.Load()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, which can take a file path or URL, TextReader or Stream as input.

Likewise, [XDocument.Load()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)(msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load(v=vs.110).aspx) has a similar set of overloads.

Comment: until now I am testing with a local file as given in the above link. I want to retrieve the xml from an URL Webservice like mydomain.com/Mixer?somevars

Comment: Yep - it's the same string overload, just with the URL!

Comment: You don't want to build an XmlDocument (DOM) if you can avoid it. Saxon will accept input from a DOM, but it's far more efficient (10x faster) to use Saxon's native tree representation.